# How to show my form inside taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, taskbar

I have created a winform application with visual studio c#, which has just two forms.

When the application is ran, the main form appears and if user presses the minimize button of it, the main form becomes hide and the other form appears.

Every things goes fine but the problem is that the second form should open inside the taskbar (like what happens in jetaudio or KMPlayer and etc.).

**Edit :**

My second form is something like this :

[image]

And i want to show it inside taskbar like below :

[image]

Comment: Can you add some code so we can suggest something  ?

Answer (score 0):

Each Form  have option ShowInTaskbar =true/false

My code   if you need

```
 [STAThread]
            public static void Main()
            {
                SysTrayApp();

                Application.Run();
            }

            private static NotifyIcon trayIcon;
            private static ContextMenu trayMenu;
            private static ContextMenu trayMenu2;

            public static void SysTrayApp()
            {
                // Create a simple tray menu with only one item.
                trayMenu2 = new ContextMenu();
                trayMenu2.MenuItems.Add("Run test2", RunTest);

                trayMenu = new ContextMenu();
                trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Run test", RunTest);
                trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Save-30", SaveData30).MergeMenu(trayMenu2);
                trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Save-80", SaveData80);
                trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Hide Log", HideLog);
                trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Show Log", ShowLog);
                trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Settings", OpenSettings);
                trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Exit", OnExit);


                // Create a tray icon. In this example we use a
                // standard system icon for simplicity, but you
                // can of course use your own custom icon too.
                trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
                trayIcon.Text = "MyTrayApp";
                trayIcon.Icon = new Icon(@"C:\Users\vladimir\Downloads\Artdesigner-Emoticons-Cool.ico", 60, 60);

                // Add menu to tray icon and show it.
                trayIcon.ContextMenu = trayMenu;
                trayIcon.Visible = true;
            }
```